# How to extract the value of serialized JSON String out of the POST HttpRequest with spring Resttemplate

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate

I'm trying to send an object with a POST HttpRequest in restTemplate.

```
restTemplate.postForObject(urlPOST, "POST", Some.class, someObject);
```

For debugging purposes i would like to get the serialized JSON string from the object out of springs restTemplate.

Where and how can I get access the json string that is sent to the server?

Comment: You could put a proxy between the client and server and capture the string on the wire

Comment: Too late!!!        This was nearly a year ago, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your breakpoint at the class

```
public abstract class AbstractHttpMessageConverter<T> implements HttpMessageConverter<T>
```

in the Method

```
public final void write(T t, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage
 outputMessage)
```

to see what the converted string!